# Why \Cache::remember and Cache::put do not write data into redis?

Tags: laravel, predis

Checking which methods can be used with writing data in redis(it is supposed that item  data would be often read and not often writte)
I found that \Cache::remember and Cache::put do not work at all !

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Library\Services\Interfaces\LogInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use App\Models\Item;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;


/*
php artisan job:dispatchNow ItemsCachingJob
*/

class ItemsCachingJob
{
    // Interface for logging messages
    protected $logger;
    use Dispatchable;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logger = app(LogInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        ...
        $ret = \Cache::remember($redisUniqueKey.'aaa', $itemsCachingHours, function() use($item) {
            return serialize( $item->toArray());
        });
        \Log::info($ret); // I see no data in redis, but I see packed string in log file

        $ret2 = Cache::put($redisUniqueKey.'bbb', serialize( $item->toArray()), $itemsCachingHours);
        \Log::info($ret2);  // I see no data in redis, but I see boolean value "1" in log file

        $ret3 = Redis::set($redisUniqueKey, serialize( $item->toArray()));
        \Log::info($ret3); // I SEE Valid data in redis with valid key and valid TTL, and I see array => Array   (
        [ Predis\Response\Status payload] => OK)

        Redis::expire($redisUniqueKey, $itemsCachingHours);
```

I used

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
```

Is it correct file to import ?

Why so ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.47", 
"predis/predis": "^2.1",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read the [Interacting with redis](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redis#interacting-with-redis) documentation? There's also docs to [setup predis](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redis#predis) correctty

Comment: Yes, I have read related docs.
In my .env file I have 
``` CACHE_DRIVER=file ```
1) Is it while Cache::remember and Cache::put  do not write write into Redis?
2) Which methods have I to use to write into redis data ParentNode/ChildNodes? Seemds redis allows such structure...

Answer (score 0):

1. please check config in ***.env*** file

```
        CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

2. for writing data into redis, you can use below code

```
        Cache::set('barcx', 'bazs', 600); // 10 Minutes
```

OR

```
        Cache::store('redis')->put('bar', 'baz', 600); // 10 Minutes
```

3. please check ***the right db(db0,db1...)*** in redis. In my trying, cache operation would like to write into db1, but normal redis operation would like to write into db0.